# Get All XML ChildNodes with Name and Value Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a requirement of getting children and subchildren values along with the tagnames and write it to XML. Is there any method of doing it in groovy. Here is my input XML

```
def employees='''<Employees>
                      <Employee>
                         <ID>123</ID>
                         <Name>xyz</Name>
                         <Addresses>
                             <Address>
                                <Country>USA</Country>
                                <ZipCode>40640</ZipCode>
                             </Address>
                          </Addresses>
                      </Employee>
                      <Employee>
                         <ID>345</ID>
                         <Name>abc</Name>
                         <Addresses>
                             <Address>
                                <Country>CA</Country>
                                <ZipCode>50640</ZipCode>
                             </Address>
                          </Addresses>
                      </Employee>
                    </Employees>'''

def lst=["ID","Addresses"]

def sw = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)
    def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(employees)
    xml.Employee{response.Employee.'**'.findAll{ node->        
           if(node.name() == str)
           {
           if(node.children().size()>0)
           {
          //get the children and subchildren of Addresses directly and write to output      
           }
           else
           {
          //get the element name and value which is not having children
            }
    }
}
}
```

My Expected output should be

```
                    <Employees>
                      <Employee>
                         <ID>123</ID>
                         <Addresses>
                             <Address>
                                <Country>USA</Country>
                                <ZipCode>40640</ZipCode>
                             </Address>
                          </Addresses>
                      </Employee>
                        <Employee>
                         <ID>345</ID>
                         <Addresses>
                             <Address>
                                <Country>CA</Country>
                                <ZipCode>50640</ZipCode>
                             </Address>
                          </Addresses>
                      </Employee>                        
                    </Employees>
```

Since ID and Adresses are present in the list

Comment: What output do you expect?  I assume there can be multiple Employees?  And each can have multiple Addresses?

Comment: @Tim_yates: I have updated the question and the expected output. yes, there can be multiple employees and addresses

Comment: @Tim_yates: I was facing the issue  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: groovy.util.XmlNodePrinter.setPreserveWhitespace(Z)V

Comment: I have no idea what code you have, all I know is you didn't seem to want to use the working code I suggested